# How do I add a Skype provider into Eclipse Communication Framework?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, skype, eclipse-ecf

I have [installed](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/3.5.5/site.p2) the Eclipse Communication Framework and now I am wanting to add a [Skype Provider](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Skype_Provider).

I have downloaded the [Skype Provider source](https://github.com/ECF/Skype) and have placed it in /eclipse/ECF-Skype/eclipse/ as stated by the third method [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Supported_dropins_formats), now I expect for a Skype provider to appear in the dropdown. Instead, I still get this:

[image]

Could someone help me install Skype for the Eclipse Communications Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check out the Skype bundles from [here](https://github.com/ECF/Skype/tree/master/bundles)  to your workspace and then you can export these Eclipse plugins and generate the OSGi bundles(JARs) from them using the Eclipse Exporters.

after generating the OSGi bundles from these eclipse plugins, you can place these plugins in the

```
<ECLIPSE_HOME>/dropins
```

location and restart your Eclipse instance.

Then you will be able to see the Skype provider available in the connections section.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana